# How to stop divs from moving when hovering over

Tags: css, html, css-float

I want a menu that simply changes colour when you hover over it and has a different colour on the active link however whenever i hover over a link it shifts the contnet in the  upwards. I also cannot get the active poart of the css to work too.
Any suggestions.

```css
div.InnerRight {
width: 7px;
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}

div.content {
line-hieght: 100%;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
margin-left: 10px;
}

td.nav {
vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;
background: rgb(160, 182, 226);
line-height: 150%;
}

td.nav:hover {
vertical-align: top;
background: rgb(25, 56, 121);
line-height: 150%;
text-decoration: underline;
color: white;
}

td.nav:active {
vertical-align: top;
background: rgb(25, 56, 121);
line-height: 150%;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<table style="text-align: left; width: 111px; height: 13px;"border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="nav"onclick="document.location.href='http://betawestsussexurologyllp.weebly.com/';">
<div class="InnerRight">
<img class="dot"alt="dot"src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/5/7/5/9/5759838/custom_themes/615015250510160105/files/dot.png?36558"><br></div><div class="content">Home<br>
</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Live example? [At JS Fiddle, perhaps](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It looks like you're explicitly telling the content to move - you have this in the hover: vertical-align: top; and this in the non-hover state: vertical-align: middle; - take that out and see if it solves your prob.

Answer (score 2):

The content moves because you have different values for `vertical-align` in hover versus non-hover.